# How to inject an HTTP request before user's request is sent

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular2-http

I'm learning Angular and as a part of, I'm trying to see how can I implement a use-case that I have in mind. At this point, I'm trying to test server communication. Namely, RxJs' Observables.

The use-case that I have in mind, is sending a POST request which requires an `X-XSRF-TOKEN` header to be accepted on the server side. This is a security header sent back to the client as a cookie the first time it sends a GET request. In other words, no conversation with the server can start with a POST request.

The way I was hoping to implement this is by wrapping the Angular's `Http` class:

```
import {Http, RequestOptions, RequestOptionsArgs, Response} from '@angular/http';
import { Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { CookieService } from 'angular2-cookie/services/cookies.service';

@Injectable()
export class RestClient {
  private static xsrfTokenCookie: string = 'XSRF-TOKEN';
  private static xsrfTokenHeader: string = 'X-XSRF-TOKEN';
  private static xsrfToken: string = null;

  constructor(private http: Http, private cookies: CookieService) {}

  get(url: string, options?: RequestOptionsArgs): Observable<Response> {
    return this.http.get(url, options);
  }

  post(url: string, body: any, options?: RequestOptionsArgs): Observable<Response> {
    if (!options) {
      options = new RequestOptions(new Headers());
    }
    if (!RestClient.xsrfToken) {
      RestClient.xsrfToken = this.cookies.get(RestClient.xsrfTokenCookie);
    }
    if (!RestClient.xsrfToken) {
      //TODO: Somehow construct an Observable object which once subscribed, it will make a GET request
      // then using the returned cookie, it will construct the actual POST request.
    }
  }
}
```

So my question is, how can I compose a POST request which sends a GET request first, waits for its response and then it will send the actual POST request. Of course, the returned Observable which `post` method's caller will get, belongs to the POST request, not the GET request. So if I write:

```
restClient.post('/', {}).subcribe(response => {
  //It's POST's response
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `mergeMap`:

```
    post(url: string, body: any, options?: RequestOptionsArgs): Observable<Response> {
        if (!options) {
          options = new RequestOptions(new Headers());
        }
        if (!RestClient.xsrfToken) {
          RestClient.xsrfToken = this.cookies.get(RestClient.xsrfTokenCookie);
        }
        if (!RestClient.xsrfToken) {
          return this.getToken(...)
                 .mergeMap(token => this.postToServer(...));
        }
      }
    }
```

In this case, `getToken` could be a **private** method that returns an `Observable` with the token value. The same applies for `postToServer`, but with return type `Observable` of `Reponse`. By creating concatenable minimal focused methods you are capsulating the logic into pieces, and by making them private you hide the implementation details.

Comment: Won't using `mergeMap` results in having the token in the final returned Observable stream? If so, that's not something I like!

Comment: Nope, mergeMap transform an observable into another basically. The returned Observable will be the one from postToServer(). Check https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/transformation/mergemap.html

Answer (score 1):

Use `flatMap`. In case you want to ignore previous request when a new request is triggered, you can use switchMap.

```
return get(getUrl,....)
   .switchMap( response => restClient.post(url, response.token .... )
```

This will return the Observable of post call.